# Как отловить потерю фокуса Qwidget'а (PyQt5)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qapplication

Как отловить потерю фокуса Qwidget'а (PyQt5). 
Необходимо закрыть приложение при потере им фокуса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void QApplication::[**focusChanged**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged)(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)

**`Этот сигнал испускается,`** когда виджет, который имеет фокус клавиатуры,
изменился со старого на настоящий, т.е. **`когда пользователь`** нажал клавишу табуляции,
щелкнул виджет или **`изменил активное окно.`** 
И старое, и настоящее могут быть nullptr.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyGui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setFocus()
        app.focusChanged.connect(self.onFocusChanged)


    def onFocusChanged(self):
        print(f' Окно активное (сфокусировано ли окно или нет) ? -> `{self.isActiveWindow()}`')
        
        if not self.isActiveWindow():
            self.close()

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MyGui()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за наводку но у меня код не работает.

Comment: Что-то не так со строкой "print(f' Окно активное (сфокусировано ли окно или нет) ? -> `{self.isActiveWindow()}`')"

Comment: В целом код решает промлему! Спасибо!

Comment: @biomotor пожалуйста. Уберите `print`, если у вас с ним что-то не так.

Comment: А можете подробно разъяснить что откуда берется и с чем соединяется, а то не оч понятно? что дает `setFocus()` ? откуда взялся `onFocusChanged` ? и как это связано с `isActiveWindow()`

Comment: @biomotor читаем: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus , https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isActiveWindow-prop , https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html